# Hosting spring 3.0 REST application?

Tags: spring, rest, hosting

I have a spring application based on Spring 3.0 for rest web services.I was planning to deploy it to heroku but facing a lot of issues.Can someone tell me some free hosting or even paid hosting where i could deploy my application?

Forgive me for my inexperience at server side

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) is a great PaaS product that offers you a Tomcat/MySQL infrastructure for your applications. I've tried the free version and I had no problems at all.

The other popular choice is go with [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/es/elasticbeanstalk/), but I haven't used it yet (mainly because of the price). A nice comparison between popular PaaS products can be found in this [DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-paasshootout/).

Comment: Just deployed it at the server.Working fine.Thanks for your recommendation.